# Shuffle of Array

Tags: objective-c, iphone, arrays, ios8, nsmutablearray

I have a tableView in which header view of section.On header view of section there is horizontal Scrollview in which load array element of any count.

```
My concern is on My first section array element look like
0 Section - 0,1,2,3
1 Section - 1 ,2,3,0
2 Section - 2,3,0,1
3 Section - 3,0,1,2
. I am using

       for (NSUInteger i = section ; i > 0; i--)
            {
                [self exchangeObjectAtIndex:i withObjectAtIndex: [appDelegate.addArray count]-i];
            }
    - (void)exchangeObjectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)idx1
    withObjectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)idx2
    {
        NSLog(@"%d",idx1-1);
         NSLog(@"%d",idx2);
        [appDelegate.addArray exchangeObjectAtIndex:idx1-1 withObjectAtIndex:idx2-1];
    }
```

They give problem because when we scroll the table array content change. Please help.

Comment: Downvoting without response just waste.

Comment: Run a search for 'array shuffle,' silly.